# How to initiate SSH connection from within a Fabric run command

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I have a remote server, say `1.2.3.4`which is running a docker container that is serving SSHD mapped to port 49222 on the docker host, so to connect to it manually I would do:

`workstation$ ssh 1.2.3.4 -t "ssh root@localhost -p 49222"` and arrive at the docker container SSH command prompt `root@f383b4f71eeb:~#`

If I run a fabric command which triggers `run('ssh root@localhost -p 49222')` then I instead am asked for the root password. However it does not accept the root password which I know to be correct, so I suspect the password prompt is originating from the host and not the docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the following task in my `fabfile.py`:

```
@task
def ssh():
    env.forward_agent = True
    run('ssh root@localhost -p 49222')
    with settings(output_prefix=False, forward_agent=True):
        run('ssh root@localhost -p 49222')
```

And in the remote servers `sshd_config` I needed to set:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

In addition, the `output_prefix=False` is useful to remove the `[hostname] run:` prefix that fabric adds to the start of every line, which is fairly annoying for every line of a remote shell.